# Getting website configuration from Magento 2 by passing in config field and website Id

Tags: magento2

How can I fetch Magento website configuration information by passing in a customers website_id.

I know how to load configuration for a store but in this instance I want to get the configuration information from the website that the customer is attached to for exporting to a ERP system where customers for a website are grouped together in customer groups.

Answer (score 2):

The answer...

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
```

and then put the website id as the final parameter.

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('link/customers/customer_category', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $account->getWebsiteId()));
```